# NullPointerException when passing / assigning values in my Classes

Tags: java

I am recieving this Error whenever I run my program :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Course.enroll(Course.java:50)
at AppCoreProcessor.enroll(AppCoreProcessor.java:62)
at CourseWindow.actionPerformed(CourseWindow.java:91)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

This is the Code that generates the exception which is implemented in my Course Class:

```
    public static void enroll(Student student){
        student.setStatus(true);
        enrollees.add(student);
    }
```

This is the Code from my AppCoreProcessor Class that calls the method:

```
    public static void enroll(int modelRow, int index) {
    oldCourse.get(modelRow).enroll(oldStudent.get(index));

    }
```

And finally this is the code that calls the enroll method from my AppCoreProcessor class:

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if(event.getSource()== enrollTo){
        AppCoreProcessor.enroll(modelRow,index);
        }
```

What I'm trying to here is that, I'm getting the selected index in my table which is exactly the same index in my ArrayList of students, and same way, getting the selected index of course from another table. I will now use these values to call the static method *enroll(int,int)* from my app processor  class. and i just cant figure out why I'm getting the NullPointerException? please help me , i'm only new to java.

Edit*  This is my implementation of my ArrayList of student and course,

```
    public class AppCoreProcessor {
private static ArrayList<Student> Student = ReadAndWrite.getDefaultStudentArrays();
private static ArrayList<Course> Course = ReadAndWrite.getDefaultCourseArrays();
```

and I'm using these Arrays as data in my JTables, And before using the enroll method, i made a System.out.println statement to display the Student at a given index and its really displaying the value, I checked the course is not null and the student is not null, but whenever i call the method of my Course Class *enroll(Student s)* to enroll the student in that course, it just throws nullpointer Exception ? which I dunno why ?

Comment: you answered your own question :). Just check if student is null or enrollees are null.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924281/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-i-have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions I ask myself in such situations:

The stacktrace you posted says the NPE is fired at line 50. Is it the `student.setStatus(true);` line or the `enrollees.add(student);` line?

If Line 50 is the `student.setStatus(true);` line then the `student` parameter is `null`. This can happen if `oldStudent.get(index)` is null, that is: the list `oldStudent` contains, at position `index` a `null` value. You'll have to go to the code that pushes value into the list and check that it does not push nulls. Note that the `oldStudent` list itself is not null. If it were then the exception would have been thrown by this line `oldCourse.get(modelRow).enroll(oldStudent.get(index));`.

If Line 50 is the `enrollees.add(student);` line then you should check the place were the `enrollees` field is assigned and make sure it is not assigned with `null`. Here is is the opposite of the first case: it is not a value inside the list but the list itself.

Comment: Hooraah! , Yes you're right! , I haven't declare the Arraylist enrollees in my Course class thats why  its NULL! , thank you so much for making me realize that.   btw. line 50 is the enrollees.add(student) .

Answer (score 1):

Either `student` is `null` OR `enrollees` is `null`. Make sure both of them are properly initialized or make a null check

```
public static void enroll(Student student){
    if(student != null && enrollees != null) {
       student.setStatus(true);
       enrollees.add(student);
    }
}
```